# Encrypting and decrypting a message with Blowfish

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, blowfish

Here is a basic code of encryping and decrypting a message:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <openssl/blowfish.h>
#include <string.h>

//gcc cryptage.c -o cryptage -lcrypto

int main(){

BF_KEY *key = malloc(sizeof(BF_KEY));

unsigned char *crypt_key = "Key of encryption";
const unsigned char *in = "Message to encrypt";
int len = strlen(crypt_key);
unsigned char *out = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);
unsigned char *result = malloc(sizeof(char)*len);


//Defining encryption key
BF_set_key(key, len, crypt_key);

//Encryption
BF_ecb_encrypt(in, out, key, BF_ENCRYPT);

//Décryption
BF_ecb_encrypt(out, result, key, BF_DECRYPT);

fprintf(stdout,"Result: %s\n",result);

return 0;

}
```

My problem is the result i get. It's always a String of 8 caracters, no more.
Can you please help me encrypt and decrypt the full message?

Thank you!

Comment: I've started typing an answer twice now and concluded that there are simply too many things to dissect, so I'm just going to say it. Blowfish is a symmetric block cipher. It operates on block-size chunks. You're encrypting one block (default BF block size is 8 bytes; 64 bits), then decrypting those bytes to a different buffer. Thus you only get your first 8 bytes.

Comment: According to the [`BF_encrypt` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/bf_encrypt): *"BF_encrypt() and BF_decrypt() are the lowest level functions for Blowfish encryption. They encrypt/decrypt the first 64 bits of the vector pointed by data, using the key key. These functions should not be used unless you implement 'modes' of Blowfish. The alternative is to use BF_ecb_encrypt(). If you still want to use these functions, you should be aware that they take each 32-bit chunk in host-byte order, which is little-endian on little-endian platforms and big-endian on big-endian ones"*.

Answer (score 1):

As @WhozCraig says, do things 8 bytes at a time.

The data to encrypt should be viewed as a byte array and not a C string.
So consider the string to encrypt with the `\0` and padded with *random* data to form a byte array that is a multiple of 8.
Call encrypt multiple times, encrypting 8 bytes per iteration.

To decrypt, call decryption the same number of iterations.  Note that the result buffer may need to be sized up to a multiple of 8.

```
const unsigned char *in = "Message to encrypt";
size_t InSize = strlen(in) + 1;
int KeyLen = strlen(crypt_key);
size_t OutSize = (InSize + 7) & (~7);
unsigned char *out = malloc(Outsize);
unsigned char *outnext = out;
//Defining encryption key
BF_set_key(key, KeyLen, crypt_key);

//Encryption
while (InSize >= 8) {    
  BF_ecb_encrypt(in, outnext, key, BF_ENCRYPT);
  in += 8;
  outnext += 8;
  InSize -= 8;
}
if (Insize > 0) {  // Cope with non-octal length
  unsigned char buf8[8];
  memcpy(buf8, in, InSize);
  for (i=InSize; i<8; i++) {
    buf8[i] = rand();
  }  
  BF_ecb_encrypt(buf8, outnext, key, BF_ENCRYPT);
}

//Décryption
unsigned char *result = malloc(OutSize);
unsigned char *resultNext = result;
while (OutSize) {
  BF_ecb_encrypt(out, resultNext, key, BF_DECRYPT);
  out += 8;
  resultNext += 8;
  OutSize -= 8;
}

fprintf(stdout,"Result: %s\n",result);
// No need to print the random bytes that were generated.
return 0;
}
```

Not quite comfortable have a known byte (`\0`) encoded in the last block.  A different length indication may be prudent.

Comment: +1 Ironically you're only a short hop from making this PKCS15 padding compatible. If you memset the trailing odd block bytes with a byte value that is the number of unused bytes (say you were three short, it would be 0x03, 0x03, 0x03) tt would allow the decryptor to know how many bytes were in the original *real* plaintext. Note: if you do this you must consider the possibility of your original plaintext being *exactly* a block size multiple, in which case you *must* add one *full* block of padding; you can't omit padding *ever*. nice answer.

Comment: @WhozCraig  Not spend to much on the PKCS15 padding, but why `0x03, 0x03, 0x03`?  Why not `Rand(), Rand(), 0x03`?  Also I assume the pad value(s) are 1 to 8?  Wonder why not 0 to 7 with 5 MSBits/byte random?

Comment: Its part of the spec for the padding algorithm. It is one of the check-methods. Aid i phatt-fingered the wrong spec. its actually 7. [See this description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) along with a multitude of other algorithms. sry for the inaccuracy. and you really don't need the random data, frankly because if you did that algorithm wouldn't be your weak link in the first place (and it isn't; the caller should be using cbc-mode; no sane person uses ecb anymore).

Comment: Thank you guys It's very helpful :) One question: `size_t OutSize = (InSize + 7)` **& (~7)**; I didn't understand what does the bold part mean ?

Comment: @HaTiMuX `7` in binary is 000...000111, all the Most-Significant bits are 0 except the 3 LSBits which are 1.  `~7` is 111...111000, all the Most-Significant bits are 1 except the 3 LSBits which are 0.  `(~7)` is simple for evaluation order clarity.  By `(InSize + 7)` anding with 111...111000, the least significant 3 bits of the sum are cleared.   You may like `((InSize + 7)/8)*8` better - similar effect.  Other forms exists.